# Is there a way to "unprotractor" a mesurement with the ruler/protractor tool?

Tags: interface, workflow, units

I sometimes accidentally protractify a measurement when using the ruler/protractor tool. Pressing <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> does nothing (I guess being a model operator it doesn't have undo implemented).

Is there any way to tell a given measurement line to go back to measuring distance and not angle?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Grab the angle point, and drag it out of the viewport window, and release. This will make it go back into measurement mode.

[image: Protractor Example]

Comment: Perfect! Just curious, how *ever* did you manage to find this?

Comment: It is actually in the wiki :P Got to the third entry in shortcuts, the end of it at [this page](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Sketching/Ruler_and_Protractor)